# Bootstrap after closing the modal set the focus to invoked element?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap 3.0.0.` I am facing a small problem in `bootstrap modal`, I want to set the focus to the element which invoked the modal window after closing the current `modal window`.

Comment: where is your code?  what have you tried?  why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Use Bootstrap's custom events:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals (last sub-section)